# How do I run commands longer than 8K symbols using CMake on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, cmake

In MS Windows `cmd.exe` command line length is restricted to 8192 characters. When calling a tool that accepts multiple files as arguments, it is easy to end up with too lengthy command line, like

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file1 file2 file3 ...
```

What to do if this is the case when calling CMake's `add_custom_target()`/`add_custom_command()` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We at KDE stumbled upon this problem with [breeze-icons](https://cgit.kde.org/breeze-icons.git) project. It used symbolic links extensively, and on Windows we had to resolve them into real files somehow. This is done in [ECMWinResolveSymlinks.cmake](https://cgit.kde.org/extra-cmake-modules.git/tree/modules/ECMWinResolveSymlinks.cmake) module.

While implementing that I had to solve long command line problem. I split long list of files into a "list of lists", where each sublist was shorter that 8192. Since lists in CMake are plain strings delimited with `;`, you can't easily create such thing as "list of lists". I had to use another delimeter, `:`, to differentiate between levels of indirection. After that I called `git` in a loop for each sublist. The splitting code looks like:

```
# In functions like _checkout_symlinks() the command line can become too lengthy for Windows.
# So we partition it, but in a hacky way due to CMake doesn't have list of lists.
function(_portioned_list outvar)
  list(LENGTH ARGN arglen)

  if(arglen EQUAL 0)
    set(${outvar} "" PARENT_SCOPE)
    return()
  endif()

  set(init)
  set(tail)
  math(EXPR range "${arglen} - 1")
  foreach(i RANGE ${range})
    list(GET ARGN ${i} v)
    string(LENGTH "${init}" initlen)
    string(LENGTH ${v} vlen)
    math(EXPR sumlen "${initlen} + ${vlen}")
    if(sumlen LESS 8192)
      list(APPEND init ${v})
    else()
      list(APPEND tail ${v})
    endif()
  endforeach()

  _portioned_list(tail_portioned ${tail})
  string(REPLACE ";" ":" init "${init}") # Generally this is not safe, because filepath can contain ':' character. But not on Windows. Phew.
  set(${outvar} ${init} ${tail_portioned} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

It can be used like:

```
file(GLOB ${dir}/* files)
_portioned_list(portioned_files ${files})
foreach(fs IN LISTS portioned_files)
  # convert back to CMake list
  string(REPLACE ":" ";" fs ${fs})
  execute_process(COMMAND ${somecommand} ${fs}
endforeach()
```